# Improper calculation of a date difference in sql

Tags: sql

I need to calculate the  difference between DFU.HISTSTART and the last Sunday which is for today is 2/27. It should be dynamic and change every Sunday.

For some reason for this calculation I am getting 3 and should get 4.

```
,ABS(DATEDIFF(wk,
     DATEADD(wk, 
     DATEDIFF(wk,6,GETDATE()), 0), DFU.HISTSTART)) 
AS '#WKS of Hist'
```

[image]

Does someone have any ideas?

Comment: You seem to be asking why 30 - 27 = 3?

Comment: @NickW difference between 01-30-22 and 02-27-22 is 4 weeks.

Comment: Apologies - I missed the month change

Comment: Please don't post [images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question) of data, sample data should be *consumable text* in your question, ideally as *create* and *insert* statements, or alternatively a [DB<>Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/). See the [question guide](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @NickW do you have an idea how it may be changed (to calculate all 4 instead of 3?)

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: I guess I'm losing it.  I swear that the op came back and said they were using T-SQL and I swear I added a tag for "tsql" and I swear this question was asked yesterday and not today. it's 13:06 local time and my post says that I posted 16 hours ago.

Answer (score 0):

You have two problems... the first is that you're trying to do the old offset trick with the "6".  That works on other date parts but not on week.  From the Microsoft Documentation...

> For a week (wk, ww) or weekday (dw) datepart, the **DATEPART return
> value depends on the value set by SET DATEFIRST**.

If your DATEFIRST is set to 7 (you can verify by running **SELECT @@DATEFIRST;**) AND your weeks start on Sundays, the following will work just fine and return a "4".

```
--===== Setup just the dates in question for a demo
DECLARE @HistStart DATE = '01-30-22'
        ,@Today    DATE = '02-27-22'
;
--===== Demo the "right" way to use "wk".
     -- I say "right" way because I don't trust DATEFIRST.
 SELECT DATEDIFF(wk,@HistStart,@Today)
;
GO
```

The second thing is that it's generally a really bad practice to depend on the DATEFIRST setting in this global computing environment. Instead, do the much more universal/bullet-proof method of using Integer math to calculate the number of weeks it's been since date-serial 6, which you correctly identified as a Sunday.

```
--===== Setup just the dates in question for a demo
DECLARE @HistStart DATE = '01-30-22'
        ,@Today    DATE = '02-27-22'
;
--===== Demo "Bulletproof" Way to calculate the difference in Weeks starting on Sunday
 SELECT DATEDIFF(dd,6,@Today)/7 - DATEDIFF(dd,6,@HistStart)/7
;
```

If you need to calculate week differences in weeks a lot, you might want to turn that into a function so that if the company decides to change the day of the week that is the start of the week, you'll only need to change it in one place.  In fact, you might want to have the function read it (the date-serial for the starting day of the week) from a "general settings table".

Comment: not sure what the basis of the @@datefirst distrust is, but why not just use @@datefirst in the calculation? see: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=ae9ac879dd831ff6d8786959afdee1d4

Comment: @PaulMaxwell - I should have said that I'm not the one that created that supposed "Best Practice".  As you clearly know, done properly, DATEFIRST can be properly used to find (for example), weeks that begin with Sunday no matter what its value is.  I just avoid it because it's considered to be a"Best Practice" (I didn't make that practice up, others did) to do so and and a lot of people heavily critique code that uses .  So, if something needs to be the same regardless of DATEFIRST, I just avoid using it and avoid the argument.

Comment: @PaulMaxwell - Also, your SET DATEFIRST 7 example is a good reason why people shouldn't use DATEFIRST.  If you change the (at)Today variable to '03-05-22', which is the Saturday of the same week that starts on '02-27-22' (Sunday), you end up with 5 weeks instead of 4 since DATEFIRST is unit based (1-7) instead of zero based (0-6) for the underlying dates.  DateSerial# of 0 = 1900-01-01, which is a Monday which makes the following Sunday have a DATESERIAL of 6 (Sunday), not 7 (also a Monday).

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this:

```
with last_sunday as (
  SELECT
  case DAYNAME(current_date())
  when 'Sun' then current_date()
  when 'Mon'then current_date()-1
  when 'Tue'then current_date()-2
  when 'Wed'then current_date()-3
  when 'Thu'then current_date()-4
  when 'Fri'then current_date()-5
  when 'Sat'then current_date()-6
  else '2020-01-01' end "SUNDAY_DATE"
)
SELECT
DFU.HIST_START_DATE
,LAST_SUNDAY.SUNDAY_DATE
,datediff(week,DFU.HIST_START_DATE,LAST_SUNDAY.SUNDAY_DATE) weeks_diff
FROM DFU
JOIN LAST_SUNDAY
;
```